# get "Build after other projects are built" project list through jenkins API

Tags: java, build, jenkins

I am exploring the Jenkins main module API as I encountered this problem:

How could we get the list of projects set in "**Build after other projects are built**" trigger?

I have found a similar method defined in class **hudson.model.AbstractProject**:: **getDownstreamProjects()**

This one returns the list of Downstream projects defined in post-build action list.

I would like to know, do we have a similar method to obtain the "Build after other projects are built" projects. If not, is their a way to get that?

Thanks